# jqgrid calculate total column cells amount depending on other column cell values

Tags: jqgrid

After using jqgrid's setFooterData function to calculate the total amount like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121350/jqgrid-access-cell-data-while-it-is-being-edited) , this is my grid and functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calculateTotal(grid_ , column_id_)
    {
        var _total_amount = 0;
        var i = getColumnIndexByName(grid_ , column_id_); 

        // TO ADD - calculate only if row "status" cell = "1:Confirmed"
        $("tbody > tr.jqgrow > td:nth-child("+(i+1)+")" , grid_[0]).each(function()
        {
            _total_amount += Number(getTextFromCell(this));
        });

        return _total_amount;
    }

    function getColumnIndexByName(grid_ , column_id_)
    {
        var cm = grid_.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
        for (var i=0,l=cm.length; i<l; i++)
        {
            if (cm[i].name===column_id_)
            {
                return i; // return the index
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    function getTextFromCell(cellNode)
    {
        return cellNode.childNodes[0].nodeName === "INPUT"?
                  cellNode.childNodes[0].value:
                  cellNode.textContent || cellNode.innerText;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var grid = $("#list"),lastSel;

        grid.jqGrid({
            url:'url',
            datatype: "xml",
            loadonce:true ,
            async: false,
            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Name' , 'Amount' , 'Status'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 65, sorttype: 'int', hidden: true },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', editable: true, width: 90, sortable: false },
                { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', editable: true, width: 70, formatter: 'number', align: 'right', sortable: false },
                {name:'status',index:'status', width:90, sorttype:"int" , editable:true,
                  edittype:"select", formatter:'select',
                  editoptions:
                  {
                     value:"1:Confirmed ;2:Open ; 3:Rejected" ,
                     dataInit: function(elem)
                     {
                        $(elem).width(90);
                     }
                  }
                },
            ],
            rowNum: 1000,
            pager: '#pager',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",                
            height: "100%",                
            footerrow:true,
            xmlReader: {
                                          root:"rows",
                                          row:"row",
                                          repeatitems:false
                                       },
            shrinkToFit: false,
            beforeSelectRow: function(row_id_, e)
            {
            },
            onSelectRow: function(id)
            {
                 grid.jqGrid('saveRow' , lastSel , false, 'clientArray');
                 grid.editRow(id , false);
                 lastSel=id;
            },
            loadComplete:function()
            {
                grid.jqGrid('footerData' , 'set' , {name:'TOTAL:' , amount: calculateTotal(grid , 'amount')});
            }
        });            
    });    
</script>
```

My question Is how can I calculate the total amount sum depending on the value that is iniside the "status" combobox. I want to sum the amount only if the value iniside the "status" cell is equels to "Confirmed" (=1).

How can this be done?

Thank's.

Comment: I forgot to mention you about some errors in your code. You should be careful with blanks and new lines. For example `value:"1:Confirmed ;2:Open ; 3:Rejected"` will be interpret as select with tree values: "1", "2", and " 3" (!!!) and the corresponding data as "Confirmed ", "Open " and "Rejected". Moreover trailing commas like "},]" at the end of `colModel` definition are syntax error. Independent from your typical style of code formatting I recommend you to use [Kernighan & Ritchie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) style because of possible ";" insert in JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made [new demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CellEditAfterSaveCellProblem2.htm) where I used another way to enumerate the cells in the grid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664587/jqgrid-load-large-data-set-without-pagination/5690583#5690583)).

In the demo I modified the code of `getTextFromCell` and `calculateTotal` functions to the following:

```
var getTextFromCell = function(cellNode) {
        if (cellNode.childNodes[0].nodeName.toUpperCase() === "SELECT") {
            var selOptions = $("option:selected", cellNode);
            if (selOptions.length>0) {
                return selOptions.text();
            }
        }
        return cellNode.childNodes[0].nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT"?
               cellNode.childNodes[0].value:
               cellNode.textContent || cellNode.innerText;
    },
    calculateTotal = function() {
        var totalAmount = 0,
            iAmount=getColumnIndexByName(grid,'amount'),
            iStatus=getColumnIndexByName(grid,'status');
        var i=0, rows = grid[0].rows, rowsCount = rows.length, row, status;

        for(;i<rowsCount;i++) {
            row = rows[i];
            if (row.className.indexOf('jqgrow') !== -1) {
                status = getTextFromCell(row.cells[iStatus]);
                if (status === "Confirmed") {
                    totalAmount += Number(getTextFromCell(row.cells[iAmount]));
                }
            }
        }

        grid.jqGrid('footerData','set',{name:'TOTAL Confirmed',amount:totalAmount});
    };
```

Now in the total lines will be displayed the sum of all values from the 'Amount' columns, but only the rows having "Confirmed" in the 'Status' column will be taken in the consideration.

Comment: Is there a way to get the value 1 instead of "confirmed"?

Comment: @user590586: I suppose you should just use `selOptions.val()` instead of `selOptions.text()`.