# How to sum the Row data while selecting the Checkbox in the JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

while selecting the checkbox in the jqgrid i need to sum the values of row data in jqgrid and i need to display those data in the footer of the jqgrid.Please help me out how to achieve that.

Thanks in Advance,
Silambarasan,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer ,i solved that issue.

The Answer is.

footerrow:true,
             userDataOnFooter:true,
              onSelectRow: function(rowId)
                        { handleSelectedRow(rowId); },

function handleSelectedRow(id) {

```
        var jqgcell     = jQuery('#list1').getCell(id, 'headerId');
        var amount     = jQuery('#list1').getCell(id, 'amount');            
        var cbIsChecked = (jQuery("#jqg_list1_"+jqgcell).attr('checked'));
     if(cbIsChecked==true)
         {

            if(amount!=null)
                {
                    totalAmt = parseInt(totalAmt) + parseInt(amount);
                }
         }else
             {
             if(amount!=null)
                {
                    totalAmt = parseInt(totalAmt) - parseInt(amount);
                }
             }

            myGrid.jqGrid('footerData','set',{needbydate:'Total Amount:',amount:totalAmt});

        }
```

The above function is used to get the values of the selected row by clicking the checkbox you will get the value from that by calling the external function like **"handleSelectedRow"** you pass your row object from that you do your operation and finally update your answer by using the jqGrid function like **"myGrid.jqGrid('footerData','set',{needbydate:'Total Amount:',amount:totalAmt}); "**
It will update in your footer.[image: I have attached the screenshot regarding this question for your reference.]

[image: Screenshot of the Onselect row sum in Footer Example.]

Comment: This is the example regarding the JQGrid on selecting the checkbox the value of the particular rows will get summed and displayed in footer in jQGrid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [footerData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008115/jqgrid-calculate-total-column-cells-amount-depending-on-other-column-cell-values/6008705#6008705) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121350/jqgrid-access-cell-data-while-it-is-being-edited/5129908#5129908) for details and demo examples.