# jqGrid subgrid button / multiselect checkbox positioning?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, datatable, grid

I'm looking for a way to move the expand/collapse button that appears when you enable a subGrid in a jqGrid from the left end of the rows to the right. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Likewise, can you control the placement of the checkbox that appears on the left when you enable multiselect?

It would be trivial if these were actually inside the colModel, but it seems to be done for you under the hood. Any way to override?

jQuery("#test").remapColumns([0,2,3,4,5,1],true,false);

seems to be close to what I need, but it doesn't play well with the "hidden" columns, like the two I'm trying to move. Moves the others as you would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just move the subgrid buttons in another position.

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860415/315935) on the close question I explained in details about the problems. Even more I made [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultiselectLast.htm) which move (under some restrictions) the multiselect checkboxs from the first to the last position:

[image]

You can try to do the same with subgrid buttons, but you should clear understand that such tricks *not supported* by jqGrid.

Comment: That's a shame. It looks/feels awkward to have the subgrid button on the left with the multiselect checkbox. Seems being on the right would be more consistent too, since you can collapse the entire grid with a button that's on the right.

Regardless, thank you for the answer.