# Changing the column position of rownumber property in JQgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have enabled 'rownumber' property. So it is displaying row numbers by inserting  a row in left most . So first column is displaying row numbers. ButI want to display row numbers in between i.e. in 3rd column.

Is there is any way to change column position?

Comment: I posted **UPDATED** part to my answer with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/customRowNumberColumn.htm) to show how to implement custom column which looks exactly like `"rn"` column added by jqGrid in case of `rownumbers: true`. You can "play" with it by changing the current page number or the number of rows per page. It displays always the same values as in `"rn"` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some columns of jqGrid have special meaning and **will be created by jqGrid** depend of the options which you use. It's `"rn"` (`rownumbers: true`), `"cb"` (`multiselect: true`) and `subgrid` (`subGrid: true`). See for example [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2438) of code. Many parts of jqGrid code just test the options and then uses the indexes of columns based on the assumption that the columns are *the first* columns in jqGrid. So it's probably theoretically possible to write the code which could move *the original* `"rn"` column to another position, but the code will be very tricky and probably long. Look at the demo of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673630/315935) for example.

So I would recommend you just add your custom column to the grid which looks like `"rn"` column and fill it with the corresponding data. The column definition could be like below

```js
{ name: "myRowNumbern", width:25, sortable: false, resizable: false, hidedlg: true,
    search: false, align: "center", fixed: true,
    classes: "ui-state-default jqgrid-rownum" }
```

**UPDATED:** I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/customRowNumberColumn.htm) which demonstrates the approach. The most important parts of the corresponding code is below:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    curRowNum: 1, // current row number parameter used in custom formatter
    colModel: [
        ...
        { name: "myRowNumbern", width: 25, sortable: false, resizable: false,
          hidedlg: true, search: false, align: "center", fixed: true,
          classes: "ui-state-default jqgrid-rownum",
          formatter: function () {
              var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
                  rn = p.curRowNum +
                      (parseInt(p.page, 10) - 1)*parseInt(p.rowNum, 10);
              p.curRowNum++;
              return rn.toString();
          } },

        ...
    ],
    loadComplete: function () {
        var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
        p.curRowNum = 1; // reset curRowNum
    }
});
```