# jQgrid - Getting issue after moving first column column(td) at last of grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have issue with jQgrid moving first column(multiselect checkbox) at last as given in this [answer by oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849786/how-to-move-a-first-td-to-last-in-a-tr/7860415#7860415).

Issue:
after select and delete the row the grid column is mis-aligned with header column.

So, how can i manage it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860415/315935), which you reference is **very old** (4.5 years ago). There are now two main forks of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop and provide under the same MIT / GNU GPLv2 licenses like it was before and the commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS available under [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I implemented many new features in free jqGrid.

The implementation of multiselect feature is rewritten. The old code of jqGrid contained many placed where the multiselect column "cb" must exist and to be at the beginning of the grid. For example, free jqGrid have new option `multiselectPosition: "left"`. You can use `multiselectPosition: "right"` to change the position of multiselect column. Additionally one can use `remapColumnsByName` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663268/315935)) or `remapColumns` to change the position of `"cb"` column (the column with multiselect checkboxes) and place it *on any place in the grid*. The main code of jqGrid is not depend on the position of the column and any place of the column is supported. One can specify any other value of `multiselectPosition`, for example, `multiselectPosition: "none"` (see [the feature list](https://github.com/mgallegos/decima-erp/blob/master/public/assets/jquery-free-jqGrid-v4.13.1/README49.md#the-following-main-new-features-are-implemented-in-the-version-49), implemented in free jqGrid 4.9.0). It will create grid with multiselect functionality *whithout any multiselect column at all*.

There are many other option, like `multiPageSelection: true`, which can be very practical too (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/multiPageSelection.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021115/315935)). Moreover one can use  `hasMultiselectCheckBox` callback to specify that `multiselect` checkbox should be created only in some specific rows of the grid instead of the default creating the checkbox in all rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oleg. The library of jQgrid which i was work on have version 4.5.2.

right now i can not able to replace because of may be it impact many place overall. So any suggestion to do some trick in it. If not then no vary :).

And again Thanks I'll will try on this new version of jQgrid...

Comment: @Draval: You are welcome! I see no way to solve the problems, which you report in the old 4.5.2. I recommend you to try to replace (temporary for the test) URLs to jqGrid files (to change 3 lines of your HTML code) to the URLs from CDN described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). You will see whether you **really have some compatibility issues or it's just a theoretical possibility**. In any way the version 4.5.2 is dead. I use 4.x.y as version numbers (currently 4.13.3) because I try to hold compatibility with old 4.x.y versions.