# jqGrid filterToolbar search

Tags: search, jqgrid

In trying to implement a `filterToolbar` search in jquery, but when I write in the textbox it doesnt send the value, the search field nor the operator: I used an example, here is the code in html file

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $("#list");
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'grid.php',
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'GET',
        deepempty:true ,
        colNames:['Id','Buscar','Desccripcion'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:65, sorttype: 'int', hidden:true, search:false},
            {name:'examen',index:'nombre', width:500, align:'left', search:true},
            {name:'descripcion',index:'descripcion', width:100, sortable:false, hidden:true, search:false}
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum:25,
        sortname: 'nombre',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        height: 'auto',
        caption: 'Examenes',
        height: "100%", 
        loadComplete: function() {
            var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');

            for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
                var id=ids[i];
                $("#"+id+ " td:eq(1)", grid[0]).tooltip({
                    content: function(response) {
                        var rowData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData',this.parentNode.id);
                        return rowData.descripcion;
                    },
                    open: function() {
                        $(this).tooltip("widget").stop(false, true).hide().slideDown("fast");
                    },
                    close: function() {
                        $(this).tooltip("widget").stop(false, true).show().slideUp("fast");
                    }
                }).tooltip("widget").addClass("ui-state-highlight");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
    $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false,
        defaultSearch: 'cn', ignoreCase: true});
});
```

and in the php file

```PHP
$ops = array(
    'eq'=>'=', //equal
    'ne'=>'<>',//not equal
    'lt'=>'<', //less than
    'le'=>'<=',//less than or equal
    'gt'=>'>', //greater than
    'ge'=>'>=',//greater than or equal
    'bw'=>'LIKE', //begins with
    'bn'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't begin with
    'in'=>'LIKE', //is in
    'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', //is not in
    'ew'=>'LIKE', //ends with
    'en'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't end with
    'cn'=>'LIKE', // contains
    'nc'=>'NOT LIKE'  //doesn't contain
);
function getWhereClause($col, $oper, $val){
    global $ops;
    if($oper == 'bw' || $oper == 'bn') $val .= '%';
    if($oper == 'ew' || $oper == 'en' ) $val = '%'.$val;
    if($oper == 'cn' || $oper == 'nc' || $oper == 'in' || $oper == 'ni') $val = '%'.$val.'%';
    return " WHERE $col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";

}
$where = ""; //if there is no search request sent by jqgrid, $where should be empty
$searchField = isset($_GET['searchField']) ? $_GET['searchField'] : false;
$searchOper = isset($_GET['searchOper']) ? $_GET['searchOper']: false;
$searchString = isset($_GET['searchString']) ? $_GET['searchString'] : false;
if ($_GET['_search'] == 'true') {
    $where = getWhereClause($searchField,$searchOper,$searchString);
}
```

I saw the query, and `$searchField`,`$searchOper`,`$searchString` have no value

But when I use the button search on the navigation bar it works! I dont konw what is happening with the `toolbarfilter`

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the option `stringResult: true` of the [toolbarfilter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention). In the case the full filter will be encoded in `filters` option (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options)). Additionally there are no `ignoreCase` option of `toolbarfilter` method. There are `ignoreCase` option of jqGrid, but it works only in case of *local* searching.

So you have to change the server code to use `filters` parameter or to remove `stringResult: true` option. The removing of `stringResult: true` could be probably the best way in your case because you have only one searchable column. In the case you will get one additional parameter on the server side: `examen`. For example if the user would type `physic` in the only searching field the parameter `examen=physic` will be send without of any information about the searching operation. If you would need to implement filter searching in more as one column and if you would use different searching operation in different columns you will have to implement searching by [filters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options) parameter.

**UPDATED**: I wanted to include some general remarks to the code which you posted. You will have bad performance because of the usage

```
$("#"+id+ " td:eq(1)", grid[0])
```

The problem is that the web browser create internally index of elements by id. So the code `$("#"+id+ " td:eq(1)")` can use the id index and will work quickly. On the other side if you use `grid[0]` as the context of jQuery operation the web browser will be unable to use the index in the case and the finding of the corresponding `<td>` element will be much more slowly in case of large number rows.

To write the most effective code you should remind, that jQuery is the wrapper of the DOM which represent the page elements. jQuery is designed to support *common* DOM interface. On the other side there are many helpful *specific* DOM method for different HTML elements. For example DOM of the `<table>` element contain very helpful [rows](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp) property which is supported by all (even very old) web browsers. In the same way DOM of `<tr>` contains property [cells](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_tr_cells.asp) which you can use directly. You can find more information about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084920/315935). In your case the only thing which you need to know is that jqGrid create additional hidden row as the first row only to have fixed width of the grid columns. So you can either just start the enumeration of the rows from the index 1 (skipping the index 0) or verify whether the class of every row is `jqgrow`. If you don't use subgrids or grouping you can use the following simple code which is equivalent your original code

```js
loadComplete: function() {
    var i, rows = this.rows, l = rows.length;

    for (i = 1; i < l; i++) { // we skip the first dummy hidden row
        $(rows[i].cells(1)).tooltip({
            content: function(response) {
                var rowData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData',this.parentNode.id);
                return rowData.descripcion;
            },
            open: function() {
                $(this).tooltip("widget").stop(false, true).hide().slideDown("fast");
            },
            close: function() {
                $(this).tooltip("widget").stop(false, true).show().slideUp("fast");
            }
        }).tooltip("widget").addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! sorry I removed stringResukt:true and nothing happened, so I try use filters, but I think Im making a mistake I wrote [height: "100%", 
 _search: true,
filters: 
   {
    "groupOp":"OR",
    "rules":[{"field":"examen","op":"cn","data":"1"}]
    
},

Comment: I am new whit this sorry, I saw the query and everytime I use the toolbar to search I have this SELECT id, nombre, descripcion FROM desc_examenes  WHERE   ''  ORDER BY nombre asc  Thank you very much

Comment: @user1208491: Sorry, but I can't follow you. Typically *the user* type any data in the input box of the searching toolbar and press Enter. So jqGrid send the request to the server with the parameters which describes the searching data. If you want to trigger searching manually in the code you should set `search: true` (Not `_search`) and set for example `filters` as property of `postData` option of jqGrid. Moreover `filters` must be not object, but JSON string. You should use `JSON.stringify` to convert object to JSON string.

Comment: Sorry, I want the user to type any data and jqgrid sen the parameters, I have only one field to search (examen) but everytime jqgrid sen the request all the parameters are empty

Comment: @user1208491: Which options of jqGrid you use now and which you get on the server side? If you for example remove `stringResult: true` then you should use `$_GET['examen']` to get the data filter data which specify the user in the filter toolbar.