# How to hide/show columns based on filter in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jQgrid to display mysql data as grid.

For few columns in grid I applied filter.
I want to show/hide columns based on filtered values. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onInitGrid` for achieve this, in this function you can show/hide columns that you want to show/hide according to filters by using `hideCol` and `showCol`.

```
jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
   url: '[sever_url]',
   mtype: "POST",
   postData: [postdata], // {name:value}
   datatype: 'json',
   colModel: [
      { index: 'column1_index', name: 'column1_name' },
      { index: 'column2_index', name: 'column2_name' },
      { index: 'column3_index', name: 'column3_name' },
      { index: 'column4_index', name: 'column4_name' },
      { index: 'column5_index', name: 'column5_name' }
   ],
   onInitGrid: function(){
      jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('hideCol','column2_name');
      jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('hideCol','column4_name');
      jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('showCol','column5_name');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beforeSearch` or `afterSearch` callback of `filterToolbar` to access `postData.filters` parameter. Alternatively you can do the same inside of `loadComplete`. You can convert it to object using `$.parseJSON` and analyse the filed where the filter set. You will get full information about the filters in the way and can call `showCol` or `hideCol`.

Look in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505932/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10811901/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953934/315935) for the corresponding code examples.