# JqGrid Traversing Through Row Data and Cell Data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am planning generate custom XML of the entire grid data for which i need to traverse through each row , and each cell of the grid.

It is easy to traverse through rows as follow. The only problem i am facing is traversing through the cells as getRowData returns key value pair instead of an array.

```
var ids = jQuery("#jgrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
//traverse the rows
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var rowdata = $("#jgrid").getRowData(ids[i]);
    var res = "";
    // Traverse the cells which does not work
    for (var j = 0; j < rowdata.length; j++) {
        ...
        ....logic to generate Xml element for each cell
    }
}
```

I dont want to hardcode column names as i plan to use it for all the grids. So the solution has to be Generic.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the simplest way to enumerate all data in the grid you can implement using [rows](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp) and [cells](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_cells.asp). It's important to understand, that jqGrid use HTML `<table>` for represent the data of the grid and `<tr>` represent the rows. jQuery objects are wrapper on DOM elements. For example `jQuery("#jgrid")[0]` is the DOM element which implements [HTMLTableElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-64060425). DOM is supported by really all web browsers, so you can safe use it. Internally jqGrid uses [HTMLTableElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-64060425), [HTMLTableRowElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-6986576) and [HTMLTableCellElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-82915075) really permanently. If you examine the source code of [getDataIDs](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.0/js/grid.base.js#L2629-2644) and [getRowData](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.0/js/grid.base.js#L2764-2800) which you use in your current code you will see that jqGrid uses `rows` DOM property of the `<table>` intensively.

In [the asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084920/315935) and in [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575634/315935) you will find an example of the code which enumerate the grid data.

In general the enumeration consists from

```js
var $grid = jQuery("#jgrid"), rows = $grid[0].rows, cRows = rows.length,
    iRow, rowId, row, cellsOfRow;

for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow++) {
    row = rows[iRow];
    if ($(row).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
        cellsOfRow = row.cells;
        // row represent the row with cellsOfRow.length cells.
        // So one can use for loop with iCol between 0 and cellsOfRow.length
        // cellsOfRow[iCol] represent the cell with the index iCol
        // and $(cellsOfRow[iCol]).text() - the text of the cell
    }
}
```