# JQGrid getRowData for all rows in certain order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to get all the rows of JQGrid in a javascript variable in a certain order.
I was able to get the data of all rows by :

```
var rowData = $("#gridId").jqGrid("getRowData");
```

But I want the rows to appear in the same order as that I entered in the grid.
I am trying to create a table and get its column details through the grid. So I require the order of the columns to remain the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: In what order are they appearing now in the variable `rowData`?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly push the jqgrid rowdata to an array and then convert that to json string.

To do that you may use a function like the one given below to iterate through the jqgrid rows:(From [Oleg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11185246/2098335))

```
var gridData= {}; 
var $grid = jQuery("#gridId"), rows = $grid[0].rows, cRows = rows.length,
    iRow, rowId, row, cellsOfRow;


for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow++) {
    row = rows[iRow];
    if ($(row).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
        cellsOfRow = row.cells;
        // row represent the row with cellsOfRow.length cells.
        // So one can use for loop with iCol between 0 and cellsOfRow.length
        // cellsOfRow[iCol] represent the cell with the index iCol
        // and $(cellsOfRow[iCol]).text() - the text of the cell
    }
}
```

Inside the loop you can push the celldata to an array.

```
gridData['column_index1'] = $(cellsOfRow[0]).text();
gridData['column_index2'] = $(cellsOfRow[1]).text();

.............................................
```

Finally convert gridData to json string using

```
var result = JSON.stringify(gridData) ;
```