# jqGrid: disable edit and delete buttons inLine edit mode

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Hi to all i'm working on jqGrid and i have a little problem trying to customize in line edit.
I would like, when a user is in editing mode on a row, disable the edit and delete buttons on the others  rows. 
Here's a link to show similar situation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116442/jqgrid-how-to-customize-inline-actions-buttons)!

This is the code i'm using to disable other rows applying the class 'not-editable-row' on the rows not selected and it works fine, but the problem is that buttons are still active and the user can click over them (and in this way also the buttons on the row change!). No action is performed but i want to know if there is a way to avoid this behavior. *emphasized text*

```
        .....
    autowidth: true,
    colNames: ["Options","Dec Id","Address1", "Address2","Rule","Action", "Subddress1", "Subddress2", "Recode","Maybereason","Maybeid"],
    colModel: [
         {name:'act',index:'act',width:55,align:'center',sortable:false,formatter:'actions',
                 formatoptions:{
                     editbutton:true,
                     delbutton:true,
                     restoreAfterError:false,
                     keys: false, // true if we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                     onEdit:function(rowid) {
                        $('#decisionGridPager').hide();
                          var myGrid =$("#decisionGrid");
                          var grid = $('#decisionGrid')[0], rows = grid.rows,cRows = rows.length, iRow, row, trClasses;
                          for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow++) {
                              row = rows[iRow]; // row.id is the rowid
                              //alert(row.id);
                              if(rowid!=row.id){
                                $(row).addClass('not-editable-row');
                                var v = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', row, 'act');

                              }//else{alert("current row");}
                          }
                     },
                     onSuccess:function(jqXHR) {
                         return true;
                     },
                     onError:function(rowid, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                          if(jqXHR.responseText !== ''){
                            alert(textStatus+": "+jqXHR.responseText);

                          }                                
                     },

                    afterSave:function(rowid) {
                         $('#decisionGridPager').show();
                         alert("record saved");
                     },
                     afterRestore:function(rowid) {
                         $('#decisionGridPager').show();
                         return false;
                     }
                 }},
        {name: "id", width: 20, hidden:true},
        {name: "address1",required:true,editable:true,edittype:'text',index:"address1",sortable:true,
          editoptions: {dataInit:vcode,size:10, maxlength: 6}, width: 20, editrules:{required:true}},
        {name: "address2", editable:true, width: 20, align: "right",editoptions: {dataInit:vcode,size:10, maxlength: 6}},
        //dataUrl:'/wacm/rulesrv?client=true' or dataUrl:'/wacm/rulesrv'
```

.......

To avoid further interactions while the user work on a row the pager is hided for example and then showed again in the afterSave function, while if occur any problem on server side and onError function is executed the user is forced to solve the problem before continue. My target is force the user to work on a single row at a time. Thanks a lot any advice will be appreciate.

Comment: Did my answer below help you out?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer at the moment i've got an error cause the line you suggest give me a syntax error and i'm working to fix this problem. I replaced the name of th grid with th name of my grid, but i can't access at th proprty.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your `if` statement where you add the `not-editable-row` class. Just replace `#gridName` with your grid's `id`:

```
if (rowid != row.id) {
    $(row).addClass('not-editable-row');
    var v = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', row, 'act');

    // hide the edit/delete buttons on non-editable rows (not the row we are editing)
    $("#gridName tr#" + row.id + " .ui-inline-edit").hide();
    $("#gridName tr#" + row.id + " .ui-inline-del").hide();
}
else {
    // show the edit/delete buttons for the current row
    $("#gridName tr#" + row.id + " .ui-inline-edit").show();
    $("#gridName tr#" + row.id + " .ui-inline-del").show();
}
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072835/jqgrid-traversing-through-row-data-and-cell-data) :

```
          for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow++) {
            row = rows[iRow]; // row.id is the rowid
            if(rowid!=row.id){
              if ($(row).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
                 $(row).hide();
               } 

          }

        }`
```

this code is used when onEdit function is called and then inside the afterSave function i restore the visibility of the rows previously hidden. I tried also another solution itrating over the cells of each row and adding the css class addClass('ui-state-disabled') but of course the user still click on the buttons, as a matter of fact 'ui-state-disabled' it's only css and can't avoid the user interaction. I don't like add and remove elements on the page but this is the only solution i found untill now.
Thanks to user3069459  any advice will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the inline edit icon for the entire grid

```
$('.ui-inline-edit').hide();
```

You can add it as part of the loadComplete event like:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $('.ui-inline-edit').hide(); 
},
```