# jqGrid. Get rows from subgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid with subgrids.

How to get rows from subGrid? What I'm doing wrong?
Below function, where i'm trying get rows, but always have errors.

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var rowIds = $("#list4").getDataIDs();

    $.each(rowIds, function (index, rowId) 
    {
        //var rows = jQuery("#list4_"+rowId+"_t").GetRowCount();
        //var rows = jQuery("#list4_"+rowId+"_t").getRowData(rowId);
        var sgtable = $("#list4_" + rowId + "_t");

        $.each(sgtable.rows, function(i, rId) //rows is undefined
        {
            console.log("rId:" + rId);
            var cdn = jQuery("#list4_"+rowId+"_t").jqGrid('getCell', rId, 'ItemTypeName');
            var cdv = jQuery("#list4_"+rowId+"_t").jqGrid('getCell', rId, 'ItemValue');

            console.log("cdn:" + cdn);
            console.log("cdv:" + cdv);
        });
    });
}  


 var rows = $("#list4_" + rowId + "_t").getDataIDs();
```

rows always == 0.

**UPDATED!**

Grid:

[image: grid]

Full code below.

```
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({

    url: getDataUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    autowidth: false,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    height: 'auto',
    loadonce:true,
    colNames: ['ContractNo', 'ParentName', 'ItemTypeName', 'ItemValue', 'ParentItemID', 'ItemID'],
    colModel: 
    [
        { name: 'ContractNo', index: 'ContractNo', hidden: true },
        { name: 'ParentName', index: 'ParentName', hidden: true },
        { name: 'ItemTypeName', index: 'ItemTypeName'/*,width: gwdth/2 */},
        { name: 'ItemValue', index: 'ItemValue'/*,width:gwdth/2*/ },
        { name: 'ParentItemID', index: 'ParentItemID', hidden: true },
        { name: 'ItemID', index: 'ItemID', hidden: true }
        ],
    subGrid: true,
    caption: "Contract items",
    subGridOptions: 
        {
            "expandOnLoad":true
        },
    gridComplete: function () {
        var rowIds = $("#list4").getDataIDs();

        $.each(rowIds, function (index, rowId) {
            $("#list4").expandSubGridRow(rowId); 

            var sdata =  $("#list4_" + rowId + "_t").getDataIDs();
             console.log("ri: "+rowId+". sdlEXP:" + sdata.length);
        });
    }, 
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) 
    {
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
       // gwdth = $('div').width();
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
        pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
        console.log("sqt_id: "+subgrid_table_id);
        $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<div style='margin-left:0px'><table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'><tr><td>Testing</td></tr></table><div id='" + pager_id + "' class='scroll'></div></div>");
        jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            colNames: ['ContractNo', 'ParentName', 'ItemTypeName', 'ItemValue', 'ParentItemID', 'ItemID'],
            colModel: 
            [
                { name: 'ContractNo', index: 'ContractNo', hidden: true  },
                { name: 'ParentName', index: 'ParentName', hidden: true },
                { name: 'ItemTypeName', index: 'ItemTypeName'/*, width: gwdth/2 - 102*/},
                { name: 'ItemValue', index: 'ItemValue'/*, width: gwdth/2*/},
                { name: 'ParentItemID', index: 'ParentItemID', hidden: true },
                { name: 'ItemID', index: 'ItemID', hidden: true }
            ],
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 20,
            //  sortorder: "asc",
            shrinkToFit: true,
            url: getDataUrl + "?subgrid=" + getCell(row_id),
            // datastr: topicjson,
            //  datatype: "jsonstring",
            datatype: "json",
            treeGrid: true,
            treeGridModel: "adjacency",
            ExpandColumn: "ItemTypeName",
            // sortname: 'ParamNameEN',
            //loadonce: true,
            ExpandColClick: true,
            // SortTree:-1,
            // sortable: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            url: getDataUrl + "&subgrid=" + getCell(row_id),
        });
    },
    loadComplete: function() {

        var sn = 150;
        var sv = 400;

        var rowIds = $("#list4").getDataIDs();
        console.log("rids:" + rowIds.length);

         $.each(rowIds, function (index, rowId) 
         {
             console.log("#list4_" + rowId + "_t");

             var sdata =  $("#list4_" + rowId + "_t").getDataIDs();
             console.log("sdl:" + sdata.length);

        });




    }  


});
```

there are outputs to console:

//loadcomplite

> rids:2 - that means we have 2 rows in main grid. It's
>   true.

But when i try to get subgrids rows, it returned 0

> sdl:0 - WHY?

But all data is loaded!

If i can't get data from subgrid in loadComplete, how to get subgrids data after grid loading?

what event I have to use?

Comment: i've discovered that I can use subgrids after loadComplete for subgrids. So how to know, that all subgrids were loaded?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are *many different ways* to implement subgrid in jqGrid. You should post mode details about your implementation.

Typically during filling of the main grid it will be just included additional column with the name "subgrid" in the `colModel` and in the grid. The column contains only an icon ("+" with the class `"ui-icon-plus"` for example) which uses the user to open subgrid. Only if the user click on the "+" symbol new additional row with subgrid will be added and filled.

So You can't find any subgrid inside of `loadComplete` of the main grid because there are just no subgrids at the moment.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084920/315935) shows how one could get *currently opened* subgrids. One can use this inside of your custom navigator button, inside of `onSelectRow` or inside of many other callbacks, but of cause not inside of `loadComplete`.

You should more detailed explain what you really need. Probably you implemented loading **all** data of the grid inclusive the data of all subgrids. **See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935)** for example. In the case you do can access all data from all subgrids.

**UPDATED**: I still don't understand what you want to do, but in any way the code which you posted have important problems. You forget that Ajax requests to the server will be processed **asynchronously**. So if you just *start loading* of subgrid from `url: getDataUrl + "&subgrid=" + getCell(row_id)` it doesn't mean that the subgrid will be already seen in the `loadComplete` of the main grid. Additionally you should understand that call of `expandSubGridRow` method will just simulate `click` event (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.3/js/grid.subgrid.js#L249-L263)) which processing could be also asynchronously.

I would forward you one more time to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935) which shows how to load all subgrid data **at once**. In the way you can solve many problems and reduce unneeded round trips to the server. Probably

Comment: @user1885734: If you want to post additional code you should **append** the text of your question with the words like **UPDATED** and any additional information. You should post short comments about modification of the code to inform people who wrote the answers before about the changes.

Comment: @user1885734: Sorry, but I can't see any code. You should *modify* the text of your question (click "edit" link at the bottom of the question) and append it with words like "**UPDATED**" and any additional new information. You should additionally inform the answers with should comment about the modification.

Comment: @user1885734: See **UPDATED** part of my answer for new information.

Comment: 1. I want iterate rows in subGrids after loading. 2. How i need to load data at once? I couldn't understand from link. What is wrong?

Comment: @user1885734: **Why** you need to do this? Do you want iterate rows after loading of the *first* subgrid or after loading of the *last* one? How one can determine which subgrid will be loaded the last? Do you can have rows with empty or no subgrids? I can continue with opened questions... If you need help from other people you should first explain your problems more clear. Why you don't want or can't load **all subgids data at once** like I suggested? The most problems which you try to solve will not exists at all in the case.

Comment: @user1885734: Look at the JSON data from **UPDATED** part of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935). The `actionSet` part of every row contains subgrid data for the current grid.

Comment: >>Why you don't want or can't load all subgids data at once like I suggested? Because I don't know how to do it. I'm newone and i'm trying to understand how it works. And the main goal was to resizing main grid according to row length in sub grids.